# Is the barycenter always at the same position?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, mass

I am currently preoccupied with the Two Body Problem and I was wondering whether the barycenter, or center of mass, is a static point or if it is moving, and how to calculate its position.

Comment: It might help if you specify moving with respect to what?

Comment: In respect to the inertial frame of the initial position

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the absence of external forces, the barycenter of any mechanical system will move in a straight line with a uniform velocity, and if the system starts off at rest (i.e. the total momentum is zero) then the barycenter will remain static for all time.

If the barycenter *does* move, then it will satisfy the newtonian equation of motion
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\mathbf R(t) = \frac1m \mathbf P(t)
\\
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\mathbf P(t) = \mathbf F(t),
\end{align}
with $\mathbf P(t)$ the total momentum of the system and $\mathbf F(t)$ the total external force acting on the system.

Comment: Does it move into one direction and then turn and move the same way back or how does this work when one orbit around this point is completed?

Comment: Do you mean with total momentum is zero that the point masses in the systems don't have a velocity or is it also when they do have a velocity to create an orbit around this point?

Comment: Emilio is basically saying the Barycenter doesn't move (in the sense that you are thinking). Assuming no external forces, there is an *inertial* frame in which the Barycenter is static. Thus, in any other *inertial* frame, the Barycenter is moving at a constant velocity in a straight line.